# When is the z-score/wald-score results will be a non-normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, z-test, wald-test

If the hypothesis is valid the distribution of scores from several samples from the same population will follow a normal distribution for the z-test. That is true?

I've made a simple experiment to see this

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import ztest
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import kstest_normal

ma= 0
mb=0
size = 100
num_exp = 10000
values = np.array([
                   ztest(np.random.normal(ma, size=size), np.random.normal(mb, size=size)) 
                   for i in range(num_exp)
])


sns.histplot(values[:,0], kde=True, label='t')

plt.title(f'mean =${values[:,0].mean():.3f}$, std={values[:,0].std():.3f}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

(Casella, G., Berger, R. L. (2002). Statistical Inference) has the following assertion for a specific case:

[image: Casella, G., Berger, R. L. (2002). Statistical Inference. pag 496]
[image: Casella, G., Berger, R. L. (2002). Statistical Inference. pag 497]

I discovered this book because of the Wikipedia page about z-test. On Wikipedia the z-test is placed with the following assumption:

> The test statistic should follow a normal distribution. Generally, one appeals to the central limit theorem to justify assuming that a test statistic varies normally. There is a great deal of statistical research on the question of when a test statistic varies approximately normally. If the variation of the test statistic is strongly non-normal, a Z-test should not be used.

Which sounds enigmatic to me. I've heard different people say that the z-test can be applied because of the central limit theorem. But, it seems that this is not true.

My question is:
**In what case are the assumptions the distribution of test scores does not follow a normal distribution?**

Comment: The primary issue you refer to, at least implicitly, is that the CLT is solely about asymptotic behavior--a limit--whereas in actual applications one has only a finite amount of data.  In that sense the answer to your question is *whenever the data are independent but not normally distributed, no Wald statistic will have exactly a Normal distribution.* But is this really what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. But no. Suppose just i.i.d , in the limit, the distribution of z-scores will always be described by a normal distribution?

Comment: My question is about this expression on Wikipedia "If the variation of the test statistic is strongly non-normal, a Z-test should not be used." which sounds cryptic to me.

Comment: That Wikipedia statement is just one implication of the difference between asymptotic behavior and behavior in finite data sets.  Whether the asymptotics are indeed Normal requires some technical criteria (that sometimes are violated in real-world problems) related to (a) a need for finite variances and (b) that the maximum likelihood estimate not asymptotically be at the boundary of the parameter space.

Comment: OK. But this statement from Wikipedia still sounds strange. I assume that the term variance used is the standard deviation of the sample distribution of the test statistics. How can a standard deviation be non-normal (or normal)?

Comment: The *distribution* is non-normal, not the sd!